# PHP file not uploading to localhost

Tags: php

I've set up an XAMPP server and trying to upload image files using a custom admin page. The page works fine when I set it up on a online server running ubuntu.

But when trying the same script in localhost gives me the following error.

**Warning :** move_upload_file(../img/products/fw000001.jpg) : failed to open stream. No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\OBS\store\kish\bin\functions.php** on line **64**

Here is the file upload part of functions.php

```
function upload_image($image,$code)
{
  define("UPLOAD_DIR", "../img/products/");

  if (!empty($image)) {
    $myFile = $image;

    if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
      return null;
    }

    //check if the file is an image
    $fileType = exif_imagetype($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    $allowed = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG);
    if (!in_array($fileType, $allowed)) {
      exit();
    }

    // ensure a safe filename
    $name = $myFile["name"];
    $parts = pathinfo($name);
    $extension = $parts["extension"];
    $savename = $code . "." . $extension;

    // don't overwrite an existing file
    $i = 0;

    if(file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $savename)) {
      unlink(UPLOAD_DIR . $savename);
    }

    // preserve file from temporary directory
    $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
    UPLOAD_DIR . $savename);
    if (!$success) {
      exit();
    }
    else
    {
      return $savename;
    }
    // set proper permissions on the new file
    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);


  }
}
```

Comment: where is this come from $myFile["name"];

Comment: @Prabhash $myFile = $image; (line 6) where $image is a $_FILE[]

Comment: I have run your code on my local and i think there is no problem with your code.Set the permission and check your form once.

Comment: if you want then i`ll show my code that i have run on my local and its working like charm.

Comment: @Prabhash form is alright, I added
chmod(UPLOAD_DIR , 0755); before uploading image let's see it works

Comment: if still does not work then try this paste this line at top.
 $image=$_FILES["image"];

Comment: @rksh where is function.php and img folder located

Comment: change this `chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);` to `chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0600);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure about directory separator. Directory separator is represent with (/) on Linux based OS. Widows is using ( \ ) for directory separator. So, please change this line and tested it.

```
 define("UPLOAD_DIR", "../img/products/");
```

to

```
 define("UPLOAD_DIR", "..".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."img".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."products".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

// preserve file from temporary directory

```
$success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],UPLOAD_DIR . $savename);
```